# Mail received while computer in sleep mode are missing

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I have a user with a very peculiar problem: if he puts his computer in sleep or hibernate mode while his Outlook 2013 client is open, he will not see any of the mail while the machine is off when he resumes it.

For instance, he put his machine in hibernation yesterday evening and, this morning, all emails received between yesterday 18:30 and this morning 09:30 where completely missing from the outlook interface.

If we perform a search in Outlook for one of the missing mail, it can be found and opened perfectly well but it is nowhere to be found in the inbox.

Messages received after the machine has been resumed are displayed fine. If Outlook is restarted, the missing mail reappears (complete with "unread" flag).

In case that matters, the server is Exchange 2013.

Any idea what could cause this and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto the **`Send and Receive`** tab in the ribbon.
2. Click on **`Send/receive all folders.`**

[image: They are found here]

Sorry... Mine is Outlook 2010 and in Norwegian... But it should be nearly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Thinkiing about it, I think it is a bug in outlook: it trusts that it will get all notifications from exchange while running and fail to take into account any "sleep" period. I haven't had the chance to test your suggestion yet but, assuming it works, it would fit that explanation. I'll update this or accept your answer as soon as I am able to test.